# Problem with XSLT transformation from Mavan to create multiple documents with result-document

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I want to transform and split a XML document. So i use "result-document" and it works. But when I try to start the XSLT with mavan, i get a output xml document just with the xml declaration.

**XSL:**

```
<xsl:result-document method="xml" href="{$filename}_{$Number}.html">
    <html>
        <head>
            <style>
body {
font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
font-size: 17pt;
line-height: 19pt;
}
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:result-document>
```

**JAVA:**

```
TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance(); 
InputStream inputStream= accessFile(xslpath);
TransformerFactoryImpl f = new net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl();
f.setAttribute("http://saxon.sf.net/feature/version-warning", Boolean.FALSE);
f.setAttribute("http://saxon.sf.net/feature/linenumbering",  Boolean.TRUE);
StreamSource schemaSource = new StreamSource(inputStream);
Transformer t = f.newTransformer(schemaSource);
StreamSource src = new StreamSource(new FileInputStream(inputpath));
StreamResult res = new StreamResult(new ByteArrayOutputStream());
t.transform(src, res);
String a= res.getOutputStream().toString();
```

What is wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is not clear in which context you get the wanted result and how that would look as you haven't provided minimal but complete samples of XML input, XSLT code, results you want and versus the ones you get. Do you expect any `xsl:result-document`s to show up in that `StreamResult` `res` or in other variables in your Java code? Or on disk as files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a wild guess, I assume that you are getting an error with the relative URIs you have in `xsl:result-document method="xml" href="{$filename}_{$Number}.html"`; as you transform to a `StreamResult` over a `ByteArrayOutputStream` I think the processor does not have an absolute base output URI against which to resolve the relative URI constructed in the `href` attribute.

Assuming the XSLT 2 processor is some version of Saxon 9 or 10, it might depend on the exact version on how to set the base output URI when using the JAXP `Transformer` API; I think with Saxon 10 you can use e.h. `((TransformerImpl)t).getUnderlyingXsltTransformer().setBaseOutputURI("file:///dir/subfolder/subsubfolder/");` to write to a certain folder.

All such things are easier and more straightforward if you change to Saxon's own API, the `s9api` (http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/using-xsl/embedding/s9api-transformation.html) where you deal with `Processor`, `XsltCompiler`, `XsltExecutable` and `XsltTransformer` or `Xslt30Transformer`.